# how to use procedure call in Apache Nifi ExecuteSQL processor (with both in and out parameter)

Tags: apache-nifi

how to use procedure call in Apache Nifi ExecuteSQL processor (with both in and out parameter) specially for talking out parameter.

Comment: What have you tried, what went wrong, what is your goal and where did you come from?

Answer (score 2):

Not with ExecuteSQL, but with ExecuteProcess you could run a command-line utility like sqlplus, here's an example of someone who got that working:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/26170/does-executesql-processor-allow-to-execute-stored.html

Also the post hints at possibly using ExecuteScript to achieve this, I have a blog post that shows the basic setup, although you'd be looking to use a CallableStatement at that point: http://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/04/sql-in-nifi-with-executescript.html